# json_encode returning null on array

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to json_encode a php array however the "choices" part is returning null.

```
Array ( [indexer] => 7 [section] => 1 [question] => What does the last paragraph indicate about an optimistic perspective? [answer] => a [choices] => There has never been a culture or religion that is genuinely optimistic`It is “a riddle of the universe”`No enlightened culture sees the world in a truly optimistic manner`Optimistic perspectives are only held by the weak )

{"indexer":"7","section":"1","question":"What does the last paragraph indicate about an optimistic perspective?","answer":"a","choices":null}
```

any ideas why?

Edit: full code:

```
$check = mysqli_query($con, "select * from questions where section = '$section' and indexer = '$question'");
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($check, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

print_r($result);
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Sounds like it doesn't like the text in the value.

Comment: i understand that. im trying to figure out why

Comment: Could you clarify: is your first line (`Array...`) from `print_r` or something? Show how you are defining that array. Are you making sure to escape all of those quotes?

Comment: @user2570937: I receive a parse error with interactive php (`php -a`).

Comment: Code works fine for me!

Comment: Works fine for me. EDIT: might have been encoding problems... EDIT2: No should work.

Comment: i've updated it with my full code. not sure why it isnt working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[json_encode](http://no.php.net/json_encode) expects all content that you're encoding to be valid UTF-8. If any part of the content isn't proper UTF-8, json_encode will fail silently for that part (b

> All string data must be UTF-8 encoded.

My guess is that the `“` marks isn't properly UTF-8 encoded (but originates from a CP1252 based encoding).

See [json_last_error](http://no.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) to retrieve the last error code from the json module.

Comment: im getting bool(true on JSON_ERROR_UTF8), my column is utf8_general_ci. How can I encode the " marks properly in UTF-8?

Comment: The relevant part would be the charset for the MySQL connection - if that's not set to UTF8 as well (with SET NAMES "utf8" or with the charset attribute in PDO or mysqli) on both insertion and retrieval, you'll get fscked up encodings. You can use iconv to convert from one charset to another, and do it recursively if needed.